# É possível realizar uma atribuição e comparação em cláusulas if em Java?

Tags: java, condição, if

É possivel atribuir e ao mesmo tempo realizar uma comparação em uma cláusula if em Java?

Por exemplo:

```
String linha = leitor.readLine();
String saida = "";
if (linha = leitor.readLine()) {
    saida += "\n";
}
```

Isso não parece funcionar.

Como eu faria?

Comment: "_É possivel atribuir e ao mesmo tempo realizar uma comparação em uma cláusula if em Java?_" Sim.

Comment: Você teria esquecido apenas da segunda pergunta @SparK =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não mostra qual é a condição que quer testar no `if`, vamos chamá-la de `condicao`:

```
if ((linha = leitor.readLine()) == condicao) {
    saida += "\n";
}
```

O código a cima irá primeiro atribuir a `linha`  o valor de `readLine` e depois fará a comparação com a `condicao`.

Answer (score 7):

Não funciona diretamente porque java não permite conversão automática para booleano. Mas você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
String linha = leitor.readLine();
String saida = "";
if ( (linha = leitor.readLine()) != null) {
    saida += "\n";
}
```

Assim como em C e C++, a atribuição é uma expressão, cujo valor é o da variável que acabou de ser atribuída. Neste caso o tipo dela é `String`, o que não é aceito dentro de um `if`. Com o conjunto de parenteses, podemos isolar o valor da atribuição e compará-lo com `null` para saber se a operação ocorreu como esperado.